# What is <?=$varname?> syntax in PHP code?

Tags: php, syntax

Previous I bumped into codes like this:

```php
<?php
  $var="hello";
?>
<?=$var?>
```

It simply prints out the content of $var, so... is the syntax equivalent to `echo $var`?
I'll also appreciate an answer pointing to a related manual page. Since the syntax is not searchable.

Comment: Short tags syntax ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php (see example there)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `<?=$var?>` is the same as `<?php echo $var; ?>`

> **From PHP.net manual:** echo also has a shortcut syntax, where you can immediately follow the opening tag with an equals sign. Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this short syntax only works with the [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) configuration setting enabled.

You can read more **[here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)**.

Comment: Also, before anyone tells you not to use it, as short tag isn't always on, it is from PHP 5.4 and on.

Comment: @RichBradshaw, good point. Just added the rest of the description to cover that.